# Is it possible to make a recursive closure in Rust?

Tags: recursion, closures, rust

This is a very simple example, but how would I do something similar to:

```
let fact = |x: u32| {
    match x {
        0 => 1,
        _ => x * fact(x - 1),
    }
};
```

I know that this specific example can be easily done with iteration, but I'm wondering if it's possible to make a recursive function in Rust for more complicated things (such as traversing trees) or if I'm required to use my own stack instead.

Comment: Niko Matsakis wrote a [wonderful post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2013/04/30/the-case-of-the-recurring-closure/) about how you can potentially (ab)use recursion in closures right now and why this will most certainly be removed (if it isn't already in `incoming`). Of course you can always define a function that calls itself, but it will not capture outer variables.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can put closures into a struct and pass this struct to the closure. You can even define structs inline in a function:

```rust
fn main() {
    struct Fact<'s> { f: &'s dyn Fn(&Fact, u32) -> u32 }
    let fact = Fact {
        f: &|fact, x| if x == 0 {1} else {x * (fact.f)(fact, x - 1)}
    };

    println!("{}", (fact.f)(&fact, 5));
}
```

This gets around the problem of having an infinite type (a function that takes itself as an argument) and the problem that `fact` isn't yet defined inside the closure itself when one writes `let fact = |x| {...}` and so one can't refer to it there.

---

Another option is to just write a recursive function as a `fn` item, which can also be defined inline in a function:

```rust
fn main() {
    fn fact(x: u32) -> u32 { if x == 0 {1} else {x * fact(x - 1)} }

    println!("{}", fact(5));
}
```

This works fine if you don't need to capture anything from the environment.

---

One more option is to use the `fn` item solution but explicitly pass the args/environment you want.

```rust
fn main() {
    struct FactEnv { base_case: u32 }
    fn fact(env: &FactEnv, x: u32) -> u32 {
        if x == 0 {env.base_case} else {x * fact(env, x - 1)}
    }

    let env =  FactEnv { base_case: 1 };
    println!("{}", fact(&env, 5));
}
```

All of these work with Rust 1.17 and have probably worked since version 0.6. The `fn`'s defined inside `fn`s are no different to those defined at the top level, except they are only accessible within the `fn` they are defined inside.

Comment: Is it actually the case that this may be disallowed in the future? As far as I can tell, this is safe because we're using `Fn`, so we have no mutable aliasing, and if you tried to write something recursive using `FnMut` the borrow checker would complain because of the multiple borrows of the `&mut FnMut()` reference.

That blog post was written against a very old version of Rust, and it looks like it's solved by the newer `Fn`/`FnMut`/`FnOnce` traits, where previously `&fn` was actually mutable.

Comment: Couldn't this ugliness be avoided if local functions simply captured their context like in most functional languages and then you could define a function instead of using the ugly closure syntax with the obvious problem for recursion ? Why does Rust have this apparently pointless and limiting difference in the way that it treats  functions and closures ?

Comment: @Andrew I think a major part is historical reasons, and that closures are harder without a garbage collector, because the context cannot just be freely captured (via the heap). Rust went through a few iterations of how closures worked before it reached the current one. They are slowly converging (e.g. closures without captures can be coerced to a `fn(...) -> ...` function pointer value), but yet not allowing closures to be declared with `fn`. FWIW, this isn't entirely simple, for instance, it would require syntax like `move fn foo(...)` to control how values are captured.

Comment: @huon thanks for the detailed answer, I hadn't considered how Rust's ownership model really complicates the apparently simply.

Answer (score 16):

As of Rust 1.62 (July 2022), there's still no *direct* way to recurse in a closure. As the other answers have pointed out, you need at least a bit of indirection, like passing the closure to itself as an argument, or moving it into a cell after creating it. These things can work, but in my opinion they're kind of gross, and they're definitely hard for Rust beginners to follow. If you want to use recursion but you have to have a closure, for example because you need something that implements `FnOnce()` to use with `thread::spawn`, then I think the cleanest approach is to use a regular `fn` function for the recursive part and to wrap it in a non-recursive closure that captures the environment. Here's an example:

```rust
let x = 5;
let fact = || {
    fn helper(arg: u64) -> u64 {
        match arg {
            0 => 1,
            _ => arg * helper(arg - 1),
        }
    }
    helper(x)
};
assert_eq!(120, fact());
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a really ugly and verbose solution I came up with:

```
use std::{
    cell::RefCell,
    rc::{Rc, Weak},
};

fn main() {
    let weak_holder: Rc<RefCell<Weak<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>>> =
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Weak::<fn(u32) -> u32>::new()));
    let weak_holder2 = weak_holder.clone();
    let fact: Rc<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32> = Rc::new(move |x| {
        let fact = weak_holder2.borrow().upgrade().unwrap();
        if x == 0 {
            1
        } else {
            x * fact(x - 1)
        }
    });
    weak_holder.replace(Rc::downgrade(&fact));

    println!("{}", fact(5)); // prints "120"
    println!("{}", fact(6)); // prints "720"
}
```

The advantages of this are that you call the function with the expected signature (no extra arguments needed), it's a closure that can capture variables (by move), it doesn't require defining any new structs, and the closure can be returned from the function or otherwise stored in a place that outlives the scope where it was created (as an `Rc<Fn...>`) and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Closure is just a `struct` with additional contexts. Therefore, you can do this to achieve recursion (suppose you want to do factorial with recursive mutable sum):

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct Fact {
    ans: i32,
}

impl Fact {
    fn call(&mut self, n: i32) -> i32 {
        if n == 0 {
            self.ans = 1;
            return 1;
        }
        self.call(n - 1);
        self.ans *= n;
        self.ans
    }
}
```

To use this struct, just:

```rust
let mut fact = Fact::default();
let ans = fact.call(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a [crate that exports a macro](https://crates.io/crates/fix_fn) to handle this more cleanly.

```rust
    use fix_fn::fix_fn;

    let fact = fix_fn!(|fact, x: u32| -> u32 {
        if x == 0 {
            1
        } else {
            x * fact(x - 1)
        }
    });

    assert_eq!(fact(5), 120);
    assert_eq!(fact(6), 720);
```

It supports `move ||` closures as well.