# How to deal with cyclic closure calls in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have the following code in Rust:

```rust
fn main() {
    let global = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    fn fn_a() {
        println!("{:?}", global);
        fn_b();
    };

    fn fn_b() {
        println!("{:?}", global);
        fn_a();
    };

    println!("Done.");
}
```

This does not compile because code in `fn` cannot capture `global`, and code in `fn_b` cannot capture `fn_a`.

I got the following error:

```rust
error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item
   --> src/main.rs:193:24
    |
193 |         println!("{}", global);
    |                        ^^^^^^
    |
    = help: use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead

error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item
   --> src/main.rs:198:24
    |
198 |         println!("{}", global);
    |                        ^^^^^^
    |
    = help: use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

(rustc --explain E0434)

So I changed to this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let global = vec!(1, 2, 3);

    let closure_a = || {
        println!("{:?}", global);
        closure_b();
    };

    let closure_b = || {
        println!("{:?}", global);
        closure_a();
    };

    println!("Done.");
}
```

but still got an error:

```rust
error[E0425]: cannot find function `closure_b` in this scope
   --> src/main.rs:195:9
    |
195 |         closure_b();
    |         ^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I guess this is because that the closure's scope begins from the line it is declared.

Is there a method to write a function/closure to call another function/closure which captures a global variable?

Comment: I don’t know if the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847890/how-to-define-mutual-recursion-with-closures is up to date, but it’s related.

Comment: I recommend against using closures here. While you can sometimes kind of make it work like in the answer of the linked question, you are much better off using either functions, passing in any additionally required data as extra parameters, or custom structs, if you really need to close over some data from the enclosing scope. This avoids the opaqueness, the limitations and the dynamic dispatch overhead of the answer in the linked question.

Comment: I've added another answer to the question tagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little and it worked for me. I

```
fn fn_b(global:Vec<i32>) {
    println!(" From B: {:?}", global);
    fn_a(global);
}
fn fn_a(global:Vec<i32>) {
    println!("From A {:?}", global);
    fn_b(global);
}
fn main() {
    let global = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    fn_a(global);
    println!("Done.");
}
```

In the methodology, I am defining the `fn_a` and `fn_b` above the function `main` and passing the vector to a function from the main .

There is another method by adding static to keyword to your vector.

```
fn main() {
    static mut Global:Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    unsafe {
        Global = vec!(1,2,3)
    }
    fn fn_a() {
        unsafe{
            println!("From A {:?}", Global);
            fn_b();
        }

    }
    fn fn_b() {
        unsafe{
            println!(" From B: {:?}", Global);
            fn_a();
        }

    }
    println!("Done.");
}
```

Check here the implementation of `unsafe`  and also do remember calling your functions `fn_a` and `fn_b`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But the reason I need a global is that I do not want to pass it to every function all over the world, if I only use it in one function of the bottom level. I haven't used any unsafe code before, I've have a try. BTW, are there any elegant way to do this? It seems not a very uncommon way to do such a thing in other language.