# Is it possible to have a closure call itself in Rust?

Tags: recursion, closures, rust

Is there a way to have closures call themselves recursively, e.g.:

```
fn main() {
    let recurse = |x: i32| { 
        println!("{}", x);
        let x_next = x + 1;
        if x < 10 {
            recurse(x_next);  // commenting this line will build
        }
        x_next;
    };

    recurse(1);
}
```

Is there a way to workaround the closure not being defined in the closure body?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946888/recursive-closure-in-rust