# Unable to create a local function because "can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item"

Tags: function, rust

Is there any way to create a local function like this Python code?

```
def h():
    final = []
    def a():
        for i in range(5):
            final.append(i)
        a()
        return final
```

I tried it, but failed:

```
fn h() -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut ff = vec![];
    fn a() {
        for i in 0..5 {
            ff.push(i)
        }
    };
    a();
    ff
}
```

```
 error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item; use the || { ... } closure form instead
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 |             ff.push(i)
  |             ^^
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Functions in Rust don't capture variables from the surrounding environment, period.  A "local" function in Rust is really just a global function that isn't globally visible; it can't do anything more than any other global function.

Instead, Rust has closures which are distinct from functions in that they *do* capture variables from their environment.  That would look like this:

```
fn h() -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut ff = vec![];
    let mut a = || {
        for i in 0..5{
            ff.push(i)
        }
    };
    a();
    ff
}
```

Three things to note with this.  Firstly, `append` is not what you want, you want `push`.  You should check the [documentation for `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) to see what's available and what methods do.  Secondly, you have to make `a` mutable because it's mutating something it captured (see also this [answer about `Fn`, `FnMut`, and `FnOnce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177395/when-does-a-closure-implement-fn-fnmut-and-fnonce#30232500)).  Third, it won't compile:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `ff` because it is borrowed
 --> <anon>:9:9
  |
3 |         let mut a = || {
  |                     -- borrow of `ff` occurs here
...
9 |         ff
  |         ^^ move out of `ff` occurs here
```

The problem is that by creating the closure, you had to give it a mutable borrow to `ff`.  However, that borrow prevents anyone else from moving or otherwise messing with `ff`.  You need to shorten the length of time this borrow exists:

```
fn h() -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut ff = vec![];
    {
        let mut a = || {
            for i in 0..5{
                ff.push(i)
            }
        };
        a();
    }
    ff
}
```

This works, but is kinda clunky.  It's also unnecessary; the above could more cleanly be rewritten by just passing the borrow to `ff` into a local function explicitly:

```
fn h() -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut ff = vec![];
    fn a(ff: &mut Vec<i32>) {
        for i in 0..5{
            ff.push(i)
        }
    }
    a(&mut ff);
    ff
}
```

This last one is the best (if you're able to use it), because it keeps it clean when and why `ff` is being borrowed.

Comment: I wonder if I can write a recursion in closure? If not, is there any way that ff is not the argument, but it mentioned in function a, and the function a is able to have recursion?

Comment: @EvaRed As I said, functions don't capture.  *Period.*  As for recursion, closures don't have names, so can't self recurse.  Even if they could, I'm not sure it would work with the implicit borrowing going on.  If you really, desperately *need* to do recursion with a closure, you can probably make it work (borrowing issues aside) using a trampoline, but that would be a different question.

Comment: @EvaRed I should probably note that a trampoline approach would likely end up being *significantly* more convoluted that just using a function and passing `&mut ff` explicitly.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to make a recursive closure in Rust?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16946888/155423)