# "can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead " while trying to parse cli arguments into a json file

Tags: rust

I am facing an error that I have failed to understand properly, maybe I have insufficient knowledge on closure and there proper use. The error is `` can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead `` I have defined closures for the `handle_app_add_new_app` in the `AppParams` impl as well. All code has been shared below.

main.rs

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::{str, io::Write as write};
use std::env;
mod utils;
use utils::*;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let chain_id = args[0];
    let chain_address = args[1];
    let appname = args[2];   
    let abi_endpoint = args[3];
    let app_address = args[4];
    let token_name = args[5];
    let token_address = args[6];

    let new_token = &TokenParams::new(&token_name, &token_address);
    let mut chain_tokens = HashMap::new();
    // Add new tokens to chain.
    chain_tokens.insert(
        new_token.token_name,
        new_token.token_address,
    );
    
    let app = AppParams::new(
        &appname, &abi_endpoint, &app_address, &chain_tokens
    );

    pub unsafe fn convert_to_u8<T: Sized>(p: &T) -> &[u8] {
        ::std::slice::from_raw_parts(
            (p as *const T) as *const u8,
            ::std::mem::size_of::<T>(),
        )
    }
    //add new application(dex,payments...etc)
    pub async fn handle_add_new_app(chain_id: &str, chain_address: &str,) -> Box<dyn Fn(ChainParams) -> ChainParams>{
        let new_app= Box::new(|x| ChainParams::new(
            &chain_id, 
            &chain_address, 
            app,
        ));
        
        let bytes: &[u8] = unsafe {convert_to_u8(&new_app) };
        let mut updated_file = OpenOptions::new().append(true).open("config.json").expect("Unable to open file"); 
        updated_file.write_all(bytes).expect("adding app to config failed");
        new_app

    }
}
```

The utils file

```
use std::{error::Error, collections::HashMap};
use serde_json::Value;

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct Addresses{
    pub to_address: String,
    pub from_address: String,
}

impl Addresses{}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct TokenParams {
    pub token_name: String,
    pub token_address: String,
}

impl TokenParams{
    /// create a new token instance
    pub  fn new(token_name: &str, token_address: &str) -> Self {
        let token_name = token_name;
        let token_address = token_address;
        TokenParams {
            token_address: token_address.to_string(),
            token_name: token_name.to_string(),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_token(chain: &str, app: &str) -> Result<Vec<Value>, Box<dyn Error>>{
        let token_getter = {
            // Load the first file into a string.
            let config = std::fs::read_to_string("Config.json").unwrap();
    
            // Parse the string into a dynamically-typed JSON structure.
            serde_json::from_str::<Value>(&config).unwrap()
        };
        // Get the get tokens with chain and app(eg dex)
        let chain_elements = token_getter[chain][app].as_array().unwrap();
        Ok(chain_elements.to_vec())
    }
}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct AppParams {
    pub appname: String,
    pub abi_endpoint: String,
    pub app_address: String,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub tokens: HashMap<String, String>
}

impl AppParams{
    /// create a new App(dex, marketplace...etc) instance
    pub fn new(appname: &str, abi_endpoint: &str, address: &str, tokens: &HashMap<String, String>) -> Box<dyn Fn(AppParams) -> AppParams> {
        let appname = appname;
        let abi_endpoint = abi_endpoint;
        let address = address;
        let mut app_tokens = HashMap::new();
        Box::new(|x| AppParams {
            appname: appname.to_string(),
            abi_endpoint: abi_endpoint.to_string(),
            tokens: app_tokens,
            app_address: address.to_string(),
        })
    }

    pub fn get_app_params(self, chain: &str) -> Result<Vec<Value>, Box<dyn Error>>{
        let app_getter = {
            // Load the first file into a string.
            let config = std::fs::read_to_string("Config.json").unwrap();
    
            // Parse the string into a dynamically-typed JSON structure.
            serde_json::from_str::<Value>(&config).unwrap()
        };
        // Get the get tokens with chain and app(eg dex)
        let chain_elements = app_getter[chain][self.appname].as_array().unwrap();
        Ok(chain_elements.to_vec())
    }
}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct ChainParams {
    pub chain_id: String,
    pub chain_address: String,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub chain_application: Vec<AppParams>,
}

impl ChainParams{

    /// get an App(dex, marketplace...etc) instance
    pub fn new(chain_id: &str, chain_address: &str, chain_application: AppParams ) -> Self {
        let chain_id = chain_id;
        let chain_address = chain_address;
        let new_tokens = HashMap::new();
        let new_application = AppParams::new(
                &chain_application.appname, 
                &chain_application.abi_endpoint, 
                &chain_application.app_address, 
                &new_tokens,
        );
        ChainParams {
            chain_id: chain_id.to_string(),
            chain_address: chain_address.to_string(),
            chain_application: vec![new_application(chain_application)],
        }
    }

    //get chain params
    pub fn get_chain_params(self) -> Result<Vec<Value>, Box<dyn Error>>{
        let app_getter = {
            // Load the first file into a string.
            let config = std::fs::read_to_string("Config.json").unwrap();
    
            // Parse the string into a dynamically-typed JSON structure.
            serde_json::from_str::<Value>(&config).unwrap()
        };
        // Get the get tokens with chain and app(eg dex)
        let chain_elements = app_getter[self.chain_id].as_array().unwrap();
        Ok(chain_elements.to_vec())
    }


}
```

A detailed explanation of your answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `convert_to_u8`?

Comment: Please always post the full error. And minimized example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create a local function because "can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895596/unable-to-create-a-local-function-because-cant-capture-dynamic-environment-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Minimized example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), produced by removing everything irrelevant to the error:

```
fn main() {
    let app = ();
    
    pub fn captures_app() {
        let _ = app;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce5121c40c1b211ae8bb7ac6fd0e97b9)

The problem here is the fact that the functions are just functions, they doesn't hold any state. Therefore, they can't refer to anything other then their arguments and `static` variables, even if they're placed inside another function; the placement governs only the name scoping, i.e. "where this identifier will refer to this function", not the access to the environment.

To see why this is a problem, consider this:

```
fn returns_fn() -> fn() {
    let app = String::from("app");
    
    pub fn captures_app() {
        println!("{}", app);
    }
    
    captures_app
}
```

Here, `fn()` is a [function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-pointer.html). Every function can be [coerced](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types) to the function pointer, therefore it must be callable by using the pointer only - but it depends on the `app` string, which can very well be different for every `returns_fn`'s call and therefore can't be integrated into the returned pointer.

---

Now, what to do about it? There are two possible courses of action.

You can pass everything the function needs via its arguments. That is, the first example would become:

```
fn main() {
    let app = ();

    pub fn captures_app(app: ()) {
        let _ = app;
    }
}
```

and your own code will look as something like this:

```
pub async fn handle_add_new_app(
    chain_id: &str,
    chain_address: &str,
    app: <return type of AppParams::new>
) -> Box<dyn Fn(ChainParams) -> ChainParams> {
    // implementation
}
```

Or you can make the function a closure instead. In minimized example, it'll be like this:

```
fn main() {
    let app = ();

    let captures_app = || {
        let _ = app;
    }
}
```

In your code, that's slightly more tricky, because async closures are unstable yet, but you can do it like this:

```
let handle_add_new_app = move |chain_id: &str, chain_address: &str| -> Box<dyn Fn(ChainParams) -> ChainParams> {
    async move {
        // implementation
    }
}
```